# How to add axis names in dtwvis?

Tags: python

I am currently trying my hand at dynamic time warping. I am using the library dtaidistance for this. I currently only get the DTW graphs as a saved image. But I would like to add axis labels to them.
Does anyone know how I can add the axis labels? I already have the following code:

```
from dtaidistance import dtw
from dtaidistance import dtw_visualisation as dtwvis

[...]

s1 = array1
s2 = array2

d, paths = dtw.warping_paths(s1, s2)
best_path = dtw.best_path(paths)

dtwvis.plot_warpingpaths(s1, s2, paths, best_path,shownumbers=True)
 

path = dtw.warping_path(s1, s2)
dtwvis.plot_warping(s1, s2, path , filename="warp.svg")


distance = dtw.distance(s1, s2)
print("DTW distance=",distance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this post](https://github.com/wannesm/dtaidistance/issues/9#issuecomment-405616795), you can simply use matplotlib the way you normally would.

You would get:

```
from dtaidistance import dtw
from dtaidistance import dtw_visualisation as dtwvis
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


s1 = np.linspace(1., 50., 2)
s2 = np.linspace(1., 50., 6)

d, paths = dtw.warping_paths(s1, s2)
best_path = dtw.best_path(paths)

dtwvis.plot_warpingpaths(s1, s2, paths, best_path,shownumbers=True)
 

path = dtw.warping_path(s1, s2)
dtwvis.plot_warping(s1, s2, path , filename="warp.svg")

# Add labels to the DTW graph
plt.xlabel('s1')
plt.ylabel('s2')
plt.show()

distance = dtw.distance(s1, s2)
print("DTW distance=",distance)
```

This code will create the following image with the given labels:
[Code visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZJHq.png)